# How to sort file contents by paragraph

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file containing below lines.

```
Number: "472"
displayname: "jack holi"

Number: "392"
displayname: "david"

Number: "376"
displayname: "joly"

Number: "481"
displayname: "john doe"

....
```

How to sort them in ascending order by number and have output like below

```
Number: "376"
displayname: "joly"

Number: "392"
displayname: "david"

Number: "472"
displayname: "jack holi"

Number: "481"
displayname: "john doe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -e 'BEGIN { $/ = "" }
         print for map $_->[1],
             sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
             map [ /Number: "(\d+)"/, $_ ],
             <>;' -- input.txt
```

The BEGIN block turns on paragraph mode, i.e. file is read by the diamond operator in paragraphs, i.e. blocks of texts separated by empty lines.

It uses [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), i.e. it maps each block to a pair `Number, block`, then sorts the pairs by the numbers and maps them back to the blocks, now in correct order.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking for an (due to the array sorting GNU) awk solution, you can use this script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { ORS= RS="\n\n" 
        FS="[\n:]"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
      }

      { gsub( /"/, "", $2)
        so[ $2 + 0 ] = $0 }

END   { for( k in so ) print so[k] }
```

Use it like this `awk -f script.awk yourfile` .

**Explanation**

- Record separator `RS` is set to two newlines, so that number and displayname become members of the same record
- Fiedld separator `FS` is set to newlline or `:` so that we get the number, displayname and their values as fields `$1,$3,$2,$4` respectively
- the record is put into `so` under the key in `$2`, `so` is sorted by (number`@ind_num_asc`)
- only in the end everything is printed

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your advise. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different take... read two lines at a time from your input file with **GNU Parallel** and put them together on a single line, sort them, then split the lines up again:

```
parallel -L2 -ra input.txt echo | sort -n | perl -pe 's/" /"\n/; $_.="\n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For earlier versions of `gawk` that don't have `PROCINFO` for array scanning order, you can do:

```
awk 'function cmp(i1, v1, i2, v2)
                   { return (i1-i2) }
     BEGIN         { ORS=RS="\n\n" } 

                   { s=$2
                     gsub(/"/, "", s)
                     arr[s]=$0 } 

     END           {
                     asorti(arr, so, "cmp") 
                     for (k in so) 
                          print arr[so[k]]}' file
```